# Vue property isn't getting passed to child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

It seems ridiculous that I can't get this to work, but when passing a prop to a child component, the value of the prop never actually changes and `disableFooterText` is always false. Am I doing something wrong?

Parent:

```
<MyChildComponent :disableFooterText="true">
```

Child:

```
<MyCustomDropdown :footerText="footerText">

props: {
  disableFooterText: {
    default: false,
    type: Boolean
  },
}

computed: {
  footerText() {
    if (this.disableFooterText) { // always false
      return '';
    }
    return 'Lorem impsum';    // always returns this value
  },
}
```

Comment: Well you will need a watcher, to look for changes in disableFooterText, call $forceUpdate() in the watcher and it should work

Comment: Is your template a string template or a DOM template? if later, use kebab-case when passing props to child.

Comment: Your code seems fine. try looking if your props are at a good level. Here is a codepen with a working example : https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-lamarr-iyqy0k?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#dom-template-parsing-caveats

Comment: Can you expand your example to include the full script block please? It might seem simple to you but we can't rule out simpler errors otherwise

Comment: @Robert where is numResultsText being used? maybe there's a typo in your template? I tested here using 'numResultsText' instead of 'footerText' and it worked without issues.

Comment: @BrancoMedeiros sorry, 'numResultsText' was a typo in my question, my code references the computed value (ie, `footerText` in my simplified code). I've updated the question reflecting the change

Answer (score 0):

Try with `kebab-case` prop:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({})

app.component('my-child-component', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <p>{{numResultsText}}</p>
    </div>
  `,
  props: {
    disableFooterText: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  computed: {
    numResultsText() {
      if (this.disableFooterText) { // always false
        return this.disableFooterText;
      }
      return 'Lorem impsum';    // always returns this value
    },
  },
})

app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
   <my-child-component :disable-footer-text="true" />
</div>
```

Comment: The child is a DOM template, so unfortunately making it kebab case won't work. My linter is calling it out anyways

Answer (score 0):

Try kebab case as @Nikola Pavicevic asked you to do, or try a `v-bind="{ disableFooterText: true }"`.